# Burns' R-Inferno p98 Puzzle?

Tags: r

Page 98 here: http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf

Reproduced below. If the following is a valid command.

```
WeirdFun()()()
```

Then what does `WeirdFun` return?

```
n = 0
weirdFun = function(x) {
  n <<- n + 1
  return(weirdFun)
}
weirdFun()
weirdFun()()
weirdFun()()()
weirdFun()()()()
```

Comment: Clearly the downvotes are because the example in R inferno is titled `weirdFun`.  Capitalization matters in R.  (Also... that is not why the downvotes are occurring)

Comment: Hint: If `<anythinghere>()` is the syntax that calls a function, it means `<anythinghere>` has to be a function. Imagine that `<anythinghere> = xyz()` what should return `xyz` function in this case? (remember that `<anythinghere>` has to be a function...)

Comment: Is the edit above the point of the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @digEmAll said, it just returns the body of the function. Here is an example...

```
weirdFun <- function() function() function() return(42)

weirdFun
#function() function() function() return(42)

weirdFun()
#function() function() return(42)
#<environment: 0x7f8cc7130390>

weirdFun()()()
#[1] 42
```

I *think* the point of the puzzle is to get you to think about closures and enclosing environments?

Comment: IMHO is just to get you to understand that functions can be treated as normal objects and thus returned by a function. e.g. `f1 <- function(){return(42)}; f2 <- function(){return(f1)}; weirdFun <- function(){return(f2)}; weirdFun()()()` is another working example...

Comment: Just closing the question. I thought it was a non-standard evaluation question. Either no one gets the point of this puzzle or it is quite pointless as most of these answers would indicate.